What should be verb tense be in figure captions?
I am confused about what verb tense should be used in captions for figures that showcase experiments that were necessarily performed in the past. Is there a norm for this, or is this question journal dependent?

Use the present tense when you can.

Also related: Past or present tense, when reporting results?

Why would the choice be any different in a figure caption than anywhere else in the paper?

In my experience, this is not only journal dependent but also editor dependent, and I had several cases where editors changed past tense to present tense but we insisted that it makes no sense and they undid that change. Present tense is appropriate when you say something like "here we demonstrate" or "we present evidence for", but an experiment that was performed in the past has a certain date attached to it and a certain chronology that implies causal relationships. It is very often important in what order experiments have taken place, and that's why English has different tenses that you must try to benefit from in your writing. Technical editing is very often outsourced, so if you feel that some changes the editor did are not to your full satisfaction, simply ask to undo them in the proof corrections with a short explanation. It always works unless your request is in violation of some official style guide, yet I am unaware of any style guide that would forbid the past tense. A specific example of the text would help to make a more specific judgement.

The verb tenses should be appropriate to the information being conveyed in the caption.
So

The graph shows results of all the Tests...

is present tense - the graph is indeed currently showing the results.

Test 7 was conducted three weeks before Test 8...

is past tense, and is noting the order of the tests which did happen in the past.
Now, when the Journal of Time Travel becomes a thing there will be additional problems to consider...

Is there any reason your captions need to be complete sentences or have verbs?
I had to take a spin through my dissertation to verify, but not a single one of my figure captions or table titles has a verb.  A non-exhaustive search through my publications reveals the same thing.  I guess that's just my writing style-- I certainly didn't do it on purpose, or even consciously.   (I clearly favor very short captions, restricting explanatory text to the, uh, to the text itself.)
But if this is something that really worries you, maybe you can do the same.
